# Does Win2k3 standard support active/active load-balanced multipath I/O?

Tags: windows-server-2003, fibre-channel

Title says it all really.  Does Windows 2003 server (Standard Edition 64 bit) support multipath I/O in active/active (load-balanced) mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it *can* but you need a DSM and matching storage system that plays nice in this way - what's your storage system?

We have it working with some of our HP EVA 8100's on 2003 64-bit by the way.

Comment: The SAN is an IBM DS8000

Comment: try this; http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=540&context=ST52G7&dc=D430&uid=ssg1S4000350&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en#DS8K

Comment: The document doesn't explicitly specify Enterprise Edition, which suggests that it will probably work on SE as well.  In fact, everything I could find on the web doesn't differentiate betwen SE and EE - I take it you're using SE on the setup you're describing above?

Comment: No, sorry, we're EE all the way - we used to use Veritas Storage Foundation for Windows v5 but it's just so damn spendy (about a grand a server) - I actually prefer the MPIO implementation on 2008 than VSF anyway.